# Stacking sensitivity analysis

Tags: neural-networks, ranking, bayesian-network, sensitivity-analysis, stacking

I conducted stacking of three algorithms (NN, J48 and BN) with logistic regression as the meta-classifier. I am interested in doing a sensitivity analysis so I am able to rank the predictors and identify the "most" important/significant predictor(s). My outcome is binary (yes, no) and I have about 20 independent variables. How can I run this sensitivity analysis?

Comment: Any suggestions?